# identifying windows installer file

Tags: c#, .net, windows-installer

I face a problem with my windows installer file of my application . 
The installer exists in 3 different web sites . Users can get the download by entering of one of the sites and install the application . 
I need a way to now each installation from which site was, and which user installed it .

For example , User 1 , download the installer from Site A .

Is there any idea,
Thanks in advance ...

Comment: do u allow only downloading the installer or (downloading+installations) of the installer too ?

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to create three different installer.

Each has to include some kind of marker, which will identify the download source. (Your user could download the file, store it to an USB-drive and bring it via NIKE-Network to a different PC.)

Do you mean windows-user oder user of the websites?

If you mean websiteuser, you may create some kind of "licensekey". This key may be the username/downloadsource combination. Than you wouldn't need to create three different setups, because you can identify the user by this key.

If you want to know the logged in windows-user, the setup-creation tool will have the capability to figure this out.